# WCF Enterprise Library ExceptionHandling failing when faultcontracttype in other project

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, enterprise-library, .net-assembly

Background:  I have a WCF project that is using Microsoft Enterprise Library WCF Exception Handling.

We recently decided to move our operation and data contracts into a separate project (.net assembly) called comanynamespace.xxx.WCF.Utilities.  After moving the operation and data contracts, I changed the faultContractType namespace to reflect the new assembly.

Now when I launch the web service in VS2010 I get the following error:

Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type ExceptionPolicyImpl, key "WCF Exception Shielding"

I have tried: ensuring the same references exist in both projects and ensuring that both projects are running under .net 4 (no client modes), etc.  Neither helped resolve the issue.

Finally, I copied the Service Fault class back into the Web Service project and changed the namespace in the web.config to point back to the local namespace:
from:

> faultContractType="comanynamespace.xxx.WCF.Utilities.ServiceFault, comanynamespace.xxx.WCF.Utilities.Services"

to:

> faultContractType="comanynamespace.xxx.Web.Services.ServiceFault, comanynamespace.xxx.Web.Services"

This does resolve the error, however, now I must have my service fault data contract in both locations.

Does anyone know why I am unable to use a service fault (data contract) in another .net assembly with Microsoft EL WCF Exception Handling?

Comment: At the top you say your project is "xxx.Utilities" but in your config you refer to it as "xxx.WCF.Utilities". Is that a typo or is it that possibly the problem?

Comment: Mike, that was a typo, but if you look at my solution below your guess about the namespace was correct in why the activation error was occurring.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up being that the namespace (second part) of the faultcontracttype was set to

> faultContractType="companyname.xxx.WCF.Utilities.Services.ServiceFault, companyname.xxx.WCF.Utilities.Services"

instead of

> faultContractType="companyname.xxx.WCF.Utilities.Services.ServiceFault, companyname.xxx.WCF.Utilities"

companyname.xxx.WCF.Utilities is the namespace for the assembly.

Comment: You should mark this as the answer so others know that it works.

Comment: Will do, in 2 days when I'm allowed. :D